# Macro and String interpolation variables

Tags: macros, haxe, string-interpolation

Giving the code

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    var i = 1;
    trace(m('some before $i some after')); // some before 1 some after
  }

  static macro function m(e: haxe.macro.Expr)
  {
    trace(e); // { expr => EConst(CString(some before $i some after)), pos => #pos(Test.hx:4: characters 12-39) }

    // trace the name of referenced var
    /* 
    trace();
    */

    return macro $e;
  }
}
```

what should I place in commented out code to `trace()` the name of the variable used inside an interpolated `String` expression without manual parsing of the string constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [`formatString`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/MacroStringTools.html#formatString):

```
class Test {
  #if !macro
  static function main() {
    var i = 1;
    trace(m('some before $i some after')); // some before 1 some after
  }
  #end
  static macro function m(e: haxe.macro.Expr)
  {
    switch e.expr {
      case EConst(CString(s)):
        trace(haxe.macro.MacroStringTools.formatString(s, e.pos));
      default:
    }
    return e; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is also what different targets use to output their interpolated strings... This actually answers my original question. And I think I should start REALLY reading through the API docs. And probably source code of your libraries on github. ;)

Comment: Neat, thanks Juraj, learn something new every day. I'll leave my answer in case folks go googling for keywords in the naive solution. :D At least I got the `case EConst(CString(str)):` thanks to Mark's recent pattern matching tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The input expression is a constant, literal String. So you have to parse out the `$i` yourself. Here's an example using a [regular expression](http://api.haxe.org/EReg.html), and for bonus points, get its type in the calling context.

http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#B0B9E (Click `Build+run`, and see both the **output** and the **compiler output** tabs)

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Context;

class Test {
  static function main() {
    var i = 1;
    trace(m('some before $i some after')); // some before 1 some after
  }

  static macro function m(e: Expr)
  {
    trace(e); // { expr => EConst(CString(some before $i some after)), pos => #pos(Test.hx:4: characters 12-39) }

    var interpolated:String = null;
    switch e.expr {
        case EConst(CString(str)):
        trace(str); // 'some before $i some after'
        var r = ~/\$\w+/;
        if (r.match(str)) { // matched(0) -> $i
          interpolated = r.matched(0).substr(1);
          trace(interpolated); // 'i'
        }
        default: throw 'Macro m expects a string literal...';
    }

    if (interpolated!=null) {
      var t = Context.typeof({expr: EConst(CIdent(interpolated)), pos:Context.currentPos()});
      trace('Got interpolated var $interpolated of type $t'); // Got interpolated var i of type TAbstract(Int,[])
    }

    return macro $e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks for a complete answer (btw. didn't think of using `Context.typeof(...)`). But actually, my question was just to check my assumption that's the only way to do it. What about `trace(m('some before ${Std.string(i)} some after'));` (http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#fEF62)? :)

Comment: Yes, the input to the macro is simply a String. Parse it however you like, regex is a lazy quick sample. There may be libraries to parse $ interpolation, I've never looked. But you might poke around: https://github.com/Simn/hxparse https://github.com/Simn/hxparse/wiki/Writing-a-Parser, which https://github.com/Simn/haxeparser is based on. Specifically this looks related to interpolation parsing: https://github.com/Simn/haxeparser/blob/master/src/haxeparser/HaxeLexer.hx#L198-L203

Comment: As far as I understand it, haxeparser won't work when used in a macro context. But actually there could be some code handling in it, so I'll just have to check if haxparse works in macros (it should).

Comment: Yes, I pointed at those as implementations as examples of better parsing than regex, and possible examples of $ interpolation parsing. Not specifically as drop-in solutions. How complex your solution depends on what you expect your inputs to be -- from simple vars to potentially arbitrary Haxe code. Assuming you may want to support expressions, once you've parsed out the contents (String) inside of the `${ ... }`, you can call `Context.parse(innerContents, Context.currentPos())` to get the AST of the inner `Expr`'s.